# Intermittent issue with addClass

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page where addClass does not seem to be working properly.   I have the same exact code in a couple places and it works in 1 but not in the other.

Here is the code:

```
if(home.length<=bowlers_team) {
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").empty();
    /* Populate the table */
    var table="table_home";
    for(var i=0; i<vis.length; i++) {
        jQuery("#"+table).append('<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+home[i]
[0]+'</td><td>'+parseInt(home[i][3])+'</td><td>'+home[i][4]+'</td></td>');
    }
} else {
console.log("Too many bowlers on Visistors.\r\n");
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").append("<span>Teams cannot exceed "+bowlers_team+" bowlers per team.</span>");
}
```

I also have:

```
        if(vis.length<=bowlers_team) {
        jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
        jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
        jQuery("#alert_window").empty();
        /* Populate the table */
        var table="table_visitor";
        for(var i=0; i<vis.length; i++) {
            jQuery("#"+table).append('<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+vis[i]
[0]+'</td><td>'+parseInt(vis[i][3])+'</td><td>'+vis[i][4]+'</td></td>');
        }
    } else {
    console.log("Too many bowlers on Visistors.\r\n");
        jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
        jQuery("#alert_window").addClass("alert alert-danger");
        jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
        jQuery("#alert_window").append("<span>Teams cannot exceed 
"+bowlers_team+" bowlers per team.</span>");
    }
```

This should create an alert if there are too many bowlers on a team.  It works fine for the home section, but does not work on the visitor portion.

It can be viewed live at https://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/scoresheet-generator.   Select the only league available.  Then select the '2017 Fall' season.  Any week or match up will do the same.   Once there, drag a bowler from the Bowlers box (only 1 at a time) to the home box.  If that team exceeds 4 bowlers, you will get the alert.   Doing the same in the visitor team does not.

Any help would be appreciated as I believe I'm having that issue on another portion of this page too (It should prompt a message if you try to drag more than 1 bowler, but it is not).

Thanks,
Chuck W

Comment: saying "it works here and doesn't work here" doesn't tell us what is wrong or what problem you are  having. What doesn't work?

Comment: Look at the first `for` loop in your question. It uses `i < vis.length`, but then accesses items from the `home` array. What if `vis.length` is 7 but `home` doesn't have that many elements? `home[i]` will be undefined and throw an error. I believe it should be `i < home.length`. That being said, you haven't provided any HTML in your code, therefore we can't replicate the issue with what you've supplied. An external link is **not** a substitute for a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Santi - thanks for the note on the vis.length, but it is not in the portion of the code that is failing.   It is the else statement below that which is not working.  The jQuery("#alert_window").addClass("alert alert-danger") is not adding when the # of vis.length <=bowlers_team.

Comment: Go to your page. Add one bowler to the visitor team. Look at console. *Error on line 101*.

Comment: Sorry Kevin B, but I thought I was clear that it was displaying an alert (in #alert_window) when the team exceed 4 bowlers for the home team but does not display the alert when the visitor team exceeds 4.   The code is setup to remove all classes from #alert_window.  Then add the class "alert alert-danger" (standard bootstrap class).  It also adds a span with an error message to the user that "Teams cannot exceed 4 bowlers per team.".   The class is not change and the alert message is not displaying.  When watching in Chrome Developer - the class is not changing.

Comment: @Chasiv Open your console in Chrome after adding a visitor. You'll see two items: One is a `console.log()` that says "Too many visitors." Look at the number on the right: `VM:57` - This is coming from line `57`, which is just before your `addClass` - This means the `addClass` is definitely firing. Now, look at the other item in console: An error on line `101`. The line just *before* this is a `removeClass()`. If this isn't convincing enough, simply add a `console.log("CLASS REMOVED");` on line `100` and the proof will be there.

Comment: In summary: Your `addClass()` is working fine. It's just that you then call `removeClass()` on line `95`. Your `if` statements seem all messed up.

Comment: Santi - thanks for your assistance.  If this was an answer, I would accept it.  You're absolutely correct.   I first check the visitor section and the error would appear, but it is overwritten by the fact there is no error when running the home team.   Your insight allowed me to fix the issue.   Silly mistake on my part, but I just wasn't thinking about the second part of the function as I wrote and tested visitor and it worked.  So I copied it to the home section.   Thanks again, your insight solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Santi pointed out, I was running the visitor portion of the code which WAS creating an error (with addClass), but then the home code was clearing the error (removeClass) if the home portion did not have an issue - thus clearing the visitor error (as it all ran in the same function).